# Inconsistency in training Iris dataset

Tags: machine-learning, backpropagation

I am a noob in the field of ML. I have been trying to classify the iris dataset. I managed to do it with backpropagation, and with 3 neurons in the hidden layer. But the mean square error that I get when I rerun the entire code is not consistent. It varies between 0 - 8%. Is this expected, or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: The thing that is different in each rerun is the initialization of weights. Different initializations will (most probably) lead to different minima, thus different errors. And what do you mean by consistent?

Comment: Welcome to the site! If you include some of your code showing how you are doing this network it will help us to give you a better answer.

Comment: Yes, I believe the random initialization might be causing different MSE. By consistent, I mean that the MSE values after each run of the code should be nearly the same. Thanks :) @AnkitSeth

Comment: @BrunoGL, the code is really dirty and uncommented, so I don't think posting it will do any help. Also, I am using some totally new activation functions. I am creating a model which could be implemented at circuit level. Thanks for offering the help. :)

Comment: @SidharthThomas I am asking your definition of consistent. You said **nearly same** - so how much range of error you are expecting to call it as nearly consistent? Different people might have different range to call it consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on Neural Networks, but if you are using Random Initialization then your MSE would vary slightly from each rerun.

Comment: You are right, but in my case the SD of the variation is around 4%. I felt that I might have done something wrong.